# Specify weights in LibSVM in Matlab

Tags: matlab, classification, libsvm

I am working on LibSVM on Matlab to solve a classification problem, the data set consist of 32 different classes. The number of instances for some classes is very low. Now I want to set the weights for every class while training a model using OvR approach, can some one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-w` parameter to specify weights for unbalanced data. From the [documentation](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/):

> -wi weight: set the parameter C of class i to weight*C, for C-SVC (default 1)

So the parameters you should pass would look something like the below. Classes with smaller number of instances should receive a higher weight:

```
-w0 10 -w1 20 -w2 30
```

Comment: Can I just multiply Parameter C with weight for every class?

Comment: This is exactly what the weights do. Parameter C is a scalar, and weights provide relative scaling. Or do I misunderstand your question somehow?